# Website who are implementing Apache Solr?

Tags: apache, search, solr, lucene, solrj

I have to admit, i had never heard of this product until my Project Manger asks me to do a little research on it and find out that if the searching capabilities of Solr will be good for a new portal we are planning to build.

I looked it up and understood it somehow but i can not find any websites which have already implemented Solr and how it will help us to enhance the User Experience.

I find out that Netflix is using it but i can not open it because Netflix is not available in my Country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in the [official solr wiki, the topic of choice is "Powered by"](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/PublicServers). eBay is the most prominent example off of my head. But the list is rather long.